# Ansible : Splitting a string based on delimiter

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following string in an ansible variable, xyz

```
xyz = "/u01/dbbackup_nfs/orabackups/odaserver-c/database/857970682/akash_2/db"
```

I want to split this string such that I stop at orabackups and do a set_fact of the variable abc , such that abc will have the following value.

```
set_fact:
  abc: "/u01/dbbackup_nfs"
```

Any suggestions on this would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration below

```yaml
  abc: "/{{ xyz.split('/')[1:3]|join('/') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  abc: /u01/dbbackup_nfs
```

---

Q: **"I needed from the first slash(/), so made it `xyz.split('/')[0:3]|join('/')`"**

A: This depends on whether the path is absolute or relative. You can use a condition if you're not sure

```yaml
  abc: |
    {% if xyz[0] == '/' %}
    /{{ xyz.split('/')[1:3]|join('/') }}
    {% else %}
    /{{ xyz.split('/')[0:2]|join('/') }}
    {% endif %}
```

The playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    abc: |
      {% if xyz[0] == '/' %}
      /{{ xyz.split('/')[1:3]|join('/') }}
      {% else %}
      /{{ xyz.split('/')[0:2]|join('/') }}
      {% endif %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ xyz.split('/')|to_yaml }}"
      vars:
        xyz: "u01/dbbackup_nfs/orabackups/odaserver-c/database/857970682/akash_2/db"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ xyz.split('/')|to_yaml }}"
      vars:
        xyz: "/u01/dbbackup_nfs/orabackups/odaserver-c/database/857970682/akash_2/db"

    - debug:
        var: abc
      vars:
        xyz: "u01/dbbackup_nfs/orabackups/odaserver-c/database/857970682/akash_2/db"

    - debug:
        var: abc
      vars:
        xyz: "/u01/dbbackup_nfs/orabackups/odaserver-c/database/857970682/akash_2/db"
```

gives

```yaml
LAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    [u01, dbbackup_nfs, orabackups, odaserver-c, database, '857970682', akash_2, db]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    ['', u01, dbbackup_nfs, orabackups, odaserver-c, database, '857970682', akash_2, db]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  abc: |-
    /u01/dbbackup_nfs

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  abc: |-
    /u01/dbbackup_nfs

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks Vladir, I needed from the first slash(/), so made it xyz.split('/')[0:3]|join('/') and it works well..

Comment: You've said you needed the first **two** elements of the path `/u01/dbbackup_nfs`. Yet `[0:3]` comprises **three** elements.

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to split this string ...*

A minimal example playbook utilizing the `split` filter in order to show how it works

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    PATH_TO_SPLIT: "/user/folder/files/db"

  tasks:

  - name: Split path
    debug:
      msg: "{{ PATH_TO_SPLIT | split ('/') }}"

  - name: Constructed path
    debug:
      msg: "/{{ PATH_TO_SPLIT.split('/')[1] }}/{{ PATH_TO_SPLIT.split('/')[2] }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Split path] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - ''
  - user
  - folder
  - files
  - db

TASK [Constructed path] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: /user/folder
```

**Further Documenation and Q&A**

- [`split` filter – split a string into a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/split_filter.html)
- [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6771046)